Placing dominoes on a 16 × 14 grid
I am placing dominoes on a 16 × 14 grid. Dominoes must be either horizontally or vertically. Each domino must cover 2 small squares. What is the minimum number of dominoes that can be placed so that no more dominoes can be placed?

 Best solution so far: It is possible to place 76.
 Lower bound: At least 75 must be placed.
 Perhaps SAT solver could be used to determine if 75 is possible.


Do the numbers on the dominoes need to match in any way, like in the dominoes game? Or are they just 1x2 rectangles with no particular markings?

They are blank and no matching rules are required.

Apparently the problem has been studied for square grids (OEIS A280984) but not for rectangular ones.

With computer search using Picat, it can be shown that Daniel's solution is the minimum.
import sat.
puzz127713(R, C, T) = B =>
	A = new_array(R+2, C+2), A :: 0..1,
	Right = new_array(R+2, C+1), Right :: 0..1,
	Down = new_array(R+1, C+2), Down :: 0..1,
	foreach(Ci in 1..C+2) A[1, Ci] #= 1, A[R+2, Ci] #= 1, Down[1, Ci] #= 0, Down[R+1, Ci] #= 0 end,
	foreach(Ri in 1..R+2) A[Ri, 1] #= 1, A[Ri, C+2] #= 1, Right[Ri, 1] #= 0, Right[Ri, C+1] #= 0 end,
	foreach(Ri in 2..R+1, Ci in 2..C+1)
		A[Ri, Ci] #= Down[Ri-1, Ci] + Down[Ri, Ci] + Right[Ri, Ci-1] + Right[Ri, Ci],
		A[Ri, Ci] #= 0 #=> A[Ri-1, Ci] #/\ A[Ri+1, Ci] #/\ A[Ri, Ci-1] #/\ A[Ri, Ci+1]
	end,
	T * 2 #= sum([A[Ri, Ci]: Ri in 2..R+1, Ci in 2..C+1]),
	solve(A),
	B = {{A[Ri, Ci]: Ci in 2..C+1}: Ri in 2..R+1}.

main =>
	R = 14, C = 16, T = 75,
	Ans = puzz127713(R, C, T),
	foreach(Row in Ans) println(Row) end,
	println(sum([Ans[Ri, Ci]: Ri in 1..R, Ci in 1..C]) // 2).

Attempt This Online!
puzz127713(R, C, T) attempts to find a placement of exactly T dominoes on a R-by-C grid that does not allow any more domino placement. The constraints encode the following:

A marks occupied cells, Right marks horizontal dominoes and Down marks vertical ones.
A is padded by one layer with all ones to avoid out-of-bounds indexing. Horizontal and vertical dominoes cannot be placed partly outside the grid, so such regions are marked as zeros.
A cell can be occupied at most once by one of the four dominoes that can cover it. If it is not occupied, all four adjacent cells must be occupied.
Exactly T * 2 cells are occupied.

With T = 76, a solution is found within a couple of seconds. With T = 75, it is reported that no solution exists in 10~20 seconds.

Not sure if this is minimum, but I can do it with

 76 dominoes

Image:

 

